# Amazon s3 batch upload

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have been trying to do batch upload using s3 client `execute()` method. It keeps throwing exception:

> Message: Argument 1 passed to Aws\AwsClient::execute() must implement interface Aws\CommandInterface, array given, called in....

Even after following the example code from the doc.

Check this example maybe I am doing something wrong:

```
$bucket   = 'myBucket';
$commands = [];

$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-west-1',
]);

$commands[] = $s3->getCommand('PutObject', [
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => 'key1.gif',
    'Body'   => 'PATH_TO_FILE_1',
]);

$commands[] = $s3->getCommand('PutObject', [
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => 'key2.gif',
    'Body'   => 'PATH_TO_FILE_2',
]);

$s3->execute($commands);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just solved this myself.

Instead of calling `$s3->execute()`, pass the client and the `$commands` array to a [CommandPool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.CommandPool.html) like so:

```
use Aws\CommandPool;

// your code here

$results = CommandPool::batch($s3, $commands);
```

You'll receive an array of results, sorted in the same order as the commands. One of the differeneces is that this will also include `Exception` objects if the command failed.

Comment: Nice one Chris.. i have been very busy and just tested today!

Comment: This things not added on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/migration.html

Comment: Here it is => https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_commands.html#commandpool